# AWS Lambda function stops all instances even the filter is configured

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

By running this code, I want to stop only insances with the tag Class:ClassB.
After testing the function, it shuts down all instances:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters = [{'Name': 'tag:Class', 'Values':['ClassB']},{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}]
    instances=ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
    for instance in instances:
        ec2.instances.stop()
        print 'stop your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Where the problem is?

Comment: Do all your instances have that tag? Code looks ok.

Comment: @helloV No, I have two instaces only with this tag! Yeah it's surprising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
instance.stop()
```

Your code is incorrect:

```
ec2.instances.stop()
```